# difference between const int& value = 12 and const int value = 12;

Tags: c++, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [const reference can be assigned an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801894/const-reference-can-be-assigned-an-int)

Is there any subtle difference between

```
const int& value = 12;
```

and

```
const int value = 12;
```

when compiling? How?

Comment: `const int& some_reference = (some rvalue);`?  Does that even work?

Comment: The latter can be used as a constant expression, the former is merely an extended-lifetime temporary.

Comment: @jogojapan : That explains what the former is (i.e. why it's legal and what it's doing), but it doesn't explain the actual _differences_ between the former and the latter (the aforementioned constant expression being one example).

Comment: @ildjarn I assumed that the _what it's doing_ part includes all information necessary to understand the difference between the former and the latter.

Comment: The question that I linked explains it in some good detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088259/literal-initialization-for-const-references

Comment: @Geoff_Montee +1 for forwarding the answer which explained the question quite well.

Comment: @jogojapan : I don't think the _implications_ of those differences are necessarily all that apparent. :-]

Answer (score 2):

```
int value = 12;
```

Here  'value' is value variable.

where is int& used to create reference variable(alias) to other variable. Like

```
int i;  
int& j=i;
```

j and i refers to same memory location. `it c++ concept.`

But reference variable can't be create for a memory location. So in my idea following expression is error promt

```
int& i = 12;  `Will not compile even.`
```

About ***const*:**

The *const* keyword is used to create a read only variable. Once initialised, the value of the variable cannot be changed.  consider following code:

```
const int x = 2;  // const var can be initialized, not modified thereafter
x = 10;           // error - cannot modify const variable
```

Error: error: assignment of read-only variable 'x'

Also Expression can using const on both sides of the type.

```
 const int value = 12;
 int const value = 12;
```

Both expressions are same(For simple non-pointer data types). learn from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness)
The most common places we see references are as function arguments or return values.

**const with reference variable**:

A temporary is created, and it's legal to bind a `const` reference to it, but illegal to bind it to a non-`const` one.

It's just like:

```
const int& reference_to_const_int = int(20);  //LEGAL
      int& reference_to_const_int = int(20);  //ILLEGAL
```

A `const` reference extends the life of a temporary, that's why this works. It's just a rule of the language. (I learnt from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801894/const-reference-can-be-assigned-an-int))

Comment: Sorry, but this is incorrect. `const int &val = 12;` is valid and should compile. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801894/const-reference-can-be-assigned-an-int

Answer (score 0):

The first is a const-reference assigned a number while the second is an const lvalue assigned a number.  In usage terms, there is no difference because neither can be modified by the user of the "value".
The compiler obviously treats the reference differently in that typically a reference is an alias of some object of the type its declared of, in this case the number without a variable name is assigned to the reference.

Answer (score -1):

See the explanation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088259/literal-initialization-for-const-references).

So you can write code like this:

```
void f( const string & s ) {
}

( "foobar" );
```

etc.

Looks like I got downvoted for giving such an incomplete answer. But this question is essentially a duplicate of the one that I linked.

There is more detailed information to describe what the difference is on that question.