# Why int& r = 0 is illegal while const int& r = 0 is legal?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

I'm new to C++. I'm trying to learn the concept of const. Could someone please tell me why the first statement is illegal while the second is legal?

```
int i = -1, &r = 0;         

const int i = -1, &r = 0;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Literal initialization for const references](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088259/literal-initialization-for-const-references)

Comment: @Zeta: that suggested dup says *"C++ does not allow: `int &ref = 7;` Because that is not logical,"* - so for the OP there the issue here - *"why first illegal while second legal"* - was obvious and left unasked.  The other question asked about `const` references, not for a contrast with non-`const`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`i` is a red herring here, the issues are `int &r = 0;` vs. `const int &r = 0;`

A non-const lvalue reference must bind directly to an lvalue. `0` is not an lvalue, so `int &r = 0;` fails.

A const lvalue reference may be bound to an rvalue. When this happens, it is not bound directly. Instead, a temporary (of type `const int` here) is created and copy-initialized from the rvalue. The temporary has its lifetime extended by virtue of this binding.

So `const int &r = 0;` is legal and has a similar effect to `const int __temp = 0; const int &r = __temp;`

Comment: note: I used double underscore on purpose to indicate that this is pseudocode

Answer (score 3):

`int i = -1, &r = 0;` is same as:

```
int i = -1;
int &r = 0;
```

The problem here is you can't write `int &r = 0;`, because initialization of a reference need the initializer to be an lvalue (an object whose address
you can take), while the literal `0` is not.

But the initializer of a const reference need not to be an lvalue, so `const int &r = 0;` is fine.

Answer (score 3):

The `i = -1,` bit creates an `i` variable initialised to `-1`, but makes no difference to the references that come after, so let's focus on:

```
int &r = 0;      // illegal
const int &r = 0;
```

What the `const int&` version does is extend the lifetime of the value it's bound to: in other words, the `0` value is kept around for use via `r`, until the end of the scope in which `r` is defined.

It's easy to point out that the same generosity is not extended to the `int&` version *"because it's not an lvalue"*.  The more interesting question of ***why*** is discussed in the [C++ FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#rval):

> In C++, non-const references can bind to lvalues and const references can bind to lvalues or rvalues, but there is nothing that can bind to a non-const rvalue. That's to protect people from changing the values of temporaries that are destroyed before their new value can be used. For example:

```
void incr(int& a) { ++a; }
int i = 0;
incr(i);    // i becomes 1
incr(0);    // error: 0 is not an lvalue
```

> If that incr(0) were allowed either some temporary that nobody ever saw would be incremented or - far worse - the value of 0 would become 1. The latter sounds silly, but there was actually a bug like that in early Fortran compilers that set aside a memory location to hold the value 0.

Comment: Since C++11 we have `int&&r = 0;` which is legal and does "suffer" from the same problems you mention

Comment: @M.M. one major distinction with `int&&` function parameters is that they are unambiguously inputs and `std::move` is introduced to ensure calling code acknowledges that explicitly where it could otherwise be surprising and problematic, while `int&` implies some manner of output and having temporaries implicitly bound is more likely to be done by accident.

Answer (score 1):

`int i = -1, &r = 0;` is basically equivalent to writing

```
int i = -1;
int &r = 0
```

The second statement tries to bind a non-`const` lvalue to `0`, which is not an lvalue at all (`0` is not an object whose address can be taken). However, it succeeds when it is a `const` lvalue as that be bound (not directly though) to an rvalue.